# ai_game is not defined

Tags: python, undefined

This is what happened when I was doing p.233, Chapter 12, Python Crash Course 2nd. I am using Visual Studio Code to write the python codes. Here is what I got. I can not proceed at this point. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem? It seems to me that some folks don't have such a problem because their code writers happen to default on defining ai_game. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen on me.

```py
import pygame
import self

class ship:
    """a class to manage the ship"""
    
    def _init_(self, ai_setting):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        
        #load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/dhip.bmp')
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        
    def blitme(self):
        """draw the ship to at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self. Image, self.rect)
```

Well, This is my second week of learning Python. It is killing me!
I tried `import ai_game` at the beginning and the VSC told me that there is no such a module in python. I am guessing if defining `ai_game` before writing the ship.py. But you see. I am obviously a rookie and have no idea of the correct direction I should seek a solution. So help me and save me.

Comment: If you're following an example that has you `import ai_game`, there's probably supposed to be a file called `ai_game.py` that you can import as a module.  The book should have already explained how modules work before it gives you an exercise that requires you to use them.  Since this is your 2nd week of learning Python and you're on chapter 12 of your book, I'm going to guess you skipped or skimmed a few chapters -- my advice is go back and take it slow!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh, come on. How do you know that I don't work hard?!

Comment: @Samwise Thanks for you response. I get a better idea of direction that I should work on from you. I will go find other books to teach myself about the modules of python because I have literally read every word before chapter 12. haha, Crying again.

Comment: Something is really off in this post. I'm the author of the book this is supposedly from, and this code is quite different from what's in the book. There's no `import self` anywhere in Python Crash Course; I've never seen `import self` anywhere in any Python code. This example has `_init_()` with single underscores (they should be double underscores), yet the answer below supposedly fixes the issue without ever mentioning this. Everything here reads like it was generated by an AI.

Comment: @japhyr Hi, author, I don't pretend to be smart because I am really new in this field. Your book is great with no doubt but the issue is that with the advancement of the tools in code writing, the tool you specifized like Sublime Text just doesn't carry out the python file. Then I switch to other advanced tools. Then an unknown AI haunts me. I am trying so hard to follow the mind of this AI while learning from your design. I really don't know which one (you or the AI) makes learning easier or more difficult.  Sometimes I wonder if your book is written for begginners or the expert.

Answer (score 0):

Do import `pygame` like this ..

```
import pygame as pg
```

the code should look like ..

```
import pygame as pg

class Ship:    
  def _init_(self, ai_setting):
    # initialize
    pg.init()
    resolution = 400, 200
    screen = pg.display.set_mode(resolution)
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
  ........
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. will try definitely. much appreciated!

Comment: Oh, my god. It just worked out. Everything has worked out. You are amazing beyond the words. If you can understand how much work a rookie needs to put in learning python, then you will feel how much appreciation I am giving you on this platform.

Comment: Thanks @Sabrina Just make my answer useful.. :)